# "Indirect reference is being made to assembly" Build Error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm on a team that manages two projects.  The Plant project is a library project that is consumed by multiple groups, including my own.  The Admin Client Project (which we are building for our client) consumes the Plant project and has it's own custom components.

To integrate, we have a dependency folder in the AdminClient.Application project that updated DLL's are put into.  So my issue is more of an annoyance that I'd like to avoid.  The Plant.UI.Winform.dll has been updated and has a version number changed.  It is reference by two projects in the AdminClient.  The actual application and an AdminClient.UI.Winform project. Both references were made to the initial version (1.0.0.0) and have their SpecificVersion property set to false.  The AdminClient.Application project also has a reference to the AdminClient.UI.Winform project.

When I clean and recompile the solution I get a [BC32207](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184598(VS.80).aspx) error.   Microsoft insists that I have to recreate all of my references.  This solution doesn't really work for me as I'd like to implement automated builds which means that the version number would be changing every time a developer does a check-in.  Does anybody know of another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson learnt.  A co-worker updated another dependency with an old version number so half the solution was built with 1.0.0.8 and the rest was trying to build using 1.0.0.9.

At least, this means that all you have to do is drop in the new dependency files and dust off the "Break the build and buy Pizza rule".